# JSDoc typedef in a separate file

Tags: jsdoc

Can I define all custom types in a separate file (e.g. `types.jsdoc`), so that they can be reused throughout the application? What's the right way to do it?

```
/**
 * 2d coordinates.
 * @typedef {Object} Coordinates
 * @property {Number} x - Coordinate x.
 * @property {Number} y - Coordinate y.
 */
```

Comment: Yes you can. You may have to add `@global` to the definitions, or experiment with the different ways to namespace stuff in JSDoc (confusing, IMHO, and for my own purposes which only is WebStorm inlineinfo/help and HTML API documentation works well).

Comment: I had the same question using Visual Studio Code. I suggested this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55767692/1244884) which you *may* find useful.

Answer (score 25):

You can define types in a module (eg. `typedefs.js`). The module contains your JSDoc typedefs and can simply export an unused property.

```js
// typedefs.js
/**
 * @typedef foo
 * @property {string} bar
 */

// etc.

exports.unused = {};
// or export {};
```

To use it, import the module where you need to reference these typedefs:

```js
const typedefs = require("./typedefs");
/** @type {typedefs.foo} */
const fb = { bar: "hello" };
```

You may wish to annotate `typedefs.js` as a `@module` or `@namespace`. Because I'm using "tsd-jsdoc" to generate a `types.d.ts` file, and due to the way TypeScript now interprets modules vs. namespaces, I've annotated my `typedefs.js` file as a `@namespace` and documented each typedef as a member of that namespace:

```js
/**
 * @namespace typedefs
 */

/**
 * @typedef foo
 * @property {string} bar
 * @memberof typedefs
 */
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: If you are using ES6 import/export, you can use `export {};` to export nothing while still marking the file as a module.

Comment: With \@module, the types would work in VSCode, but the links in generated docs were broken. With \@namespace, both VSCode and generated docs work. Been looking for this solution for a long time. Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

This is a TypeScript-flavored JSDoc specific answer, but I'm having success using a [triple-slash directive](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/triple-slash-directives.html) to "import" all the types from another file. This has the advantage of not actually adding an unused `import` which can upset linters and bundlers.

I'm putting my shared types in one file called `typedefs.js` like this:

```
// typedefs.js
/**
 * @typedef {Object} Foo
 * @property {string} bar
 */

/**
 * @typedef {Object} Baz
 * @property {number} buzz
 */
```

and then using `/// <reference path="typedefs.js" />` in the other files to access the shared types like this:

```
// randomThing.js
/// <reference path="typedefs.js" />

/**
 * Turn a Foo into a Baz
 *
 * @param {Foo} a
 * @return {Baz}
export function (a) {
  return { buzz: a.bar.length };
}
```

The tricky thing though is that now `typedefs.js` is just being referenced in a comment, bundlers like rollup miss it completely. So I'm combining it with my old `consts.js` that exports a few constants and is imported in at least one place. That way the typedefs are still included in the rollup output.

I hope someone else finds this helpful.

p.s. rollup will completely exclude a pure JSDoc `typedefs.js` file _even if you have `import './typedefs.js'` because of tree-shaking! Gotta run rollup with `--no-treeshake` to keep those comments in the rollup output.

Comment: well. maybe I spoke too soon. doesn't seem to be working now, sheesh.

Comment: Actually this was the one option that worked for me. VSCode 1.44.0

Comment: does it render on webpage when we use the typedefs to one of the function param. @WilliamHilton

Comment: worked like a charm thank you <3 wonder if it works for external differences (urls)

Answer (score 6):

In vscode, the `import('./path/to/types.js').def` tag works perfectly fine.

For e.g.
`types.js`

```
/**
 * @typedef {Object} connection
 * @property {String} id
 * @property {Number} pingRetries
 * @property {(data:Object) => void} sendJSON
 */
exports.unused = {};
```

And `someFile.js`

```
/**
 * @param {import('./types').connection} param
 */
const someFunc = (param) => {}
```

Also, note that the `exports.unused = {}` is **necessary** in the `types.js` file, otherwise the auto-import of `import('./types')` would not work and you may have to type it by yourself.

Answer (score 4):

I just tried with VSCode and it works only if the separate file is opened in the editor. If not, external typedefs are typed as any

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I was excited to see that my types were picked up and I thought it was from the workspace, but it stopped when I closed the file as you'd suggested.

Comment: Yeah, this is what I just finally discovered... Did you ever find a solution for this? I've been trying things for hours now with no luck. :/

Comment: Using v1.68.0 even though the file is not opened it is resolving the types.  Yay!

Answer (score 2):

I usually do something similar in my projects, the difference being I use the extension `.js` to name the file. Webstorm works perfectly and is able to check types and auto-complete just fine. It won't recognize the `.jsdoc` extension (I just checked), so stick to `.js` even if the file doesn't contain any code statement.

Answer (score 2):

I've had success with simply creating my types in a `typedefs.js` file and referencing using the ts/vscode `import(path/to/file).Foo` tag. JSDoc does not support this syntax out of the box, so I suggest also using [jsdoc-tsimport-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdoc-tsimport-plugin) in order to parse your docs.

Eg: typedef.js:

```js
/**
 * @typedef {Object} Foo
 * @property {string} id
 */

/**
 * @typedef {Object} Bar
 * @property {string[]} things
 */

// having to export an empty object here is annoying, 
// but required for vscode to pass on your types. 
export {};
```

coolFunction.js

```js
/**
 * This function is super dope
 * @param {import('../typedef').Foo[]} foo - a foo
 * @return {import('../typedef').Bar[]} bar - an array of bars
 */

 export function (foo) {
    // do cool things
    return bar;
 }
```

I'm also using [tsd-jsdoc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsd-jsdoc) to create a `types.d.ts` file, and this implementation is successfully creating the types. I had trouble with declaring `modules` and `namespaces` with the types file— just creating standalone `typedefs` for said models worked best for me.