# Use JSDoc to reference a @class from another module

Tags: javascript, node.js, jsdoc

I have two JavaScript repos, **libA** and **libB**. In **libB**, I have a module, `utilities.js`:

```js
/**
 * @class
 * @classdesc Class for doing stuff
 */
class MyClass {...}
```

Now in **libA**, I have a module, `defs.js`:

```js
/**
 * @typedef {Object} UtilitiesFromB
 * @property {import("libB/utilities").MyClass} myClass - An instance of MyClass
 */
```

This does *NOT* work. However, if use `@typedef` on MyClass, then it *does* work (but I don't want to do that, since @typedef has no way of defining object methods, only properties).

```js
/**
 * @typedef {Object} MyClass
 * @class
 * @classdesc Class for doing stuff
 */
class MyClass {...}
```

How do I get the type definition I created in **libA/defs.js** to be able to correctly reference MyClass as a property?

Comment: Perhaps this question helps? https://stackoverflow.com/q/45836847/1244884

Comment: Maybe this answer would work for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43183450/jsdoc-typedef-in-a-separate-file#answer-55306135. Basically you need to require() one file from another one for `MyClass` to become available